# onClick action in child component is sending wrong element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, react-props

I'm trying to render some child components that contain some collapsibles using MateralizeCss, and inside each collapsible three tabs are present, and on each tab there is a button also each of the collapsible headers is assigned a name that I pass through the props.

now on OnClick event of each of those buttons, I call a function which updates the state of the child component with the tab which is selected ('easy', 'med' or hard), something like `this.setState({active: this.button.parentname})` and return the name of that collapsible to the parent, but the problem is that the returned name is not the correct one, it is of the first child which was first rendered.

to understand this, suppose I have state in my parent component like.

```
{category: [

    {"name": 1, .. some other properties}, // data of first collapsible 
    {"name": 2, .. some other properties}, // second

]}
```

Initially, the state is empty but later the category is being filled asynchronously, but I've handled that.

so I render it like this,

```
<ul className="collapsible">
     {this.state.category.length > 0 ? (this.state.category.map(((category, key) => (
    <CategoryCollapsible key={key} category={category} get_name={this.get_name} />
   )))) : null}
</ul>
```

and on child component side I just have the `<li>` tag inside which the collapsible headers' name is `this.props.category.name`.

and in the body I just have tabs with button with onClick as I defined above, i.e. return the header name of the collapsible.

so, what could be the reason for this?
why is react being confused between the two rendered child components?

I also checked the props using `ComponentDidMount()` and the props are correct, but as soon as the onClick event is happening the props are just changed to the first one?
what is this sorcery?
any guesses?

Comment: @MattOestreich I tried to replicate My issue on CodeSandbox but looks like materalize is causing an issue of crossorigins https://codesandbox.io/s/boz91?fontsize=14 here is the link

Comment: Actually when the button is clicked a bodal is popped us which has a form, I didn't mention imyhe question about the form to reduce the complexity, so I just mentioned about the name, but In reality I want the contents of the form and the name of the collapsible. So you can imafome the scenerio like, we have a component which is rendering collapsible inside then there are tabs (easy, med, hard) and on each tab there is a button which pops up a form and on Onsubmit of the form I want form data and the collapsible name was passed as props and send it to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I fixed it, actually each of the collapsible needed a unique ID, so I just put the `name` as the id of the collapsible.

to conclude we can deduce that each functionality (element) child component must have a unique id's to identify them for any function to identify them.